# Undefined property: App\Models\Product::$category Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a simple inventory system using Laravel 8.
I want to join two tables: `category` and `products`

Category table:

| id | categoryname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | drink |
| 2 | biscuits |
| 3 | toy |

Products table:

| id | prodname | catid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fanta | 1 |
| 2 | apple juice | 1 |
| 3 | buildblocks | 3 |

I need the data passed to the table as the below output

| id | productname | categoryname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fanta | drink |

While running the program I got the error as:

> Undefined property: App\Models\Product::$category

**Category**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'catname',
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product', 'id', 'catid');
    }
}
```

**Products**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'prodname',
        'catid',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'category', 'id');
    }
}
```

**view.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($products as $key => $product)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $key }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $product->prodname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $product->category->catname }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function view()
    {
        $products = Product::with('category')->get();
        $categories = Category::with('product')->get();
   
        return view('product.view')-> with([
            'products' => $products,
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/products', [ProductController::class, 'view']);
```

Comment: Is the foreign key `catid` or `category` in the products table?

Comment: yes foreign key catid in the products table

Comment: i add the database table above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken in model here is an example
**change catid to category_id
your colum in product table should be category_id in databsse to**

**In My user table**

```
public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Employee::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

**Here is my employee table**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

**You have to work on you controller methods look here**

```
 public function showEmployee()
    {
       
        $emps   = User::with('employee');
        
        return view('employee.show_emp', compact('emps'));
    }
```

**Routes like this**

```
Route::resource('showEmployee','EmpController@showEmployee');
```

Here is an Your solution I am Trying to put my comfort.

**Category**

use App\Models\Product;

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'catname',
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'catid', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Products**

use App\Models\Category;

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'prodname',
        'catid',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    



public function view()
    {
       
        $products = Product::with('category')->get();
        $categories = Category::with('product')->get();
        
        return view('employee.show_emp', compact('products', 'categories'));
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('products','ProductController@view');
```

Add these both lines to your both models after namspace one of each
For **Category**

```
use App\Models\Product;
```

For **Product**

```
use App\Models\Category;
```

> Note: this is untested code

Comment: upvote or approve my answer if you find solution

Comment: working only this problem on the  view.blade.php Attempt to read property "catname" on null (View: E:\laravelprjo\pos\resources\views\products\view.blade.php)

Comment: it through error on null means,  they can't find catname from category table by using product. See my model example hasOne and belongsTo both used to make Relationship b/w two table. Try to access product name by category if accessible means you have to change relationship basic rules

Comment: please help me write it i tired many times join two table i cannot

Comment: look carefully in my example, change you code following my code then try to refresh. Your code on model to make relationship is wrong.

Comment: yeah i solve so many times like this type of error, all was from relationship error

Comment: ya i tried above code working only the problem catname not displayed

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships            visit this url you can understand

Comment: <td>{{ $product->category->catname }}</td> this how i wrote in the view

Comment: yeah man i can see, you can  access your product table that is local but can't access foreign table that is category.   return $this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

Comment: return $this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key'); where going to write this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238222/discussion-between-ronny-dsouza-and-programmer-hari).

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key passed to the relationship is incorrect and the property you are trying to access in the view does not exist.

Please try out the following changes:

Products.php:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'catid', 'id');
}
```

view:

```
{{ $product->category->categoryname }}
```

[One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: ya. after changed it i got the error was Call to undefined relationship [product] on model [App\Models\Category].

Comment: The Category model has relation defined as `products` not `product`

Comment: where i am going to change it

Comment: In your controller, `Category::with('products')->get();`

Comment: Undefined variable $products i am getting a error i think error coming from view.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

Simple follow Laravel conventions and you avoid to your problems in the future.

https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions

**Table structure:**

```
categories
    id - integer
    name - string

products
    id - integer
    category_id - integer
    name - string
```

**Category model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**Product model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('products', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::with('category')->get();

        return view('product.index', compact('products'));
    }
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($products as $product)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>

                <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>

                <td>{{ $product->category->name }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```